# Php mysqli prepare vs query

Tags: mysqli, php, запрос

Возник вопрос, что безопаснее/лучше/грамотнее юзать. Сейчас на сайте используется ещё старая библиотека mysql, собираюсь переводить на mysqli объектную.
Дает ли мне что-либо использование метода prepare? Я так понимаю, его фишка в защите от инъекций из-за типизации и не только. Если использовать просто метод ->query, будет ли это опаснее?

P.S. У меня свои методы приёма GET/POST:

```
class Http
{

    public static function Get($request) {
        $result = @$_GET[$request];
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $result = stripslashes($result);
        }
        $link = Repo::db_connect();
        $result = mysql_real_escape_string($result, $link);
        Repo::db_close();

        return $result;
    }

    public static function Post($request) {
        $result = @$_POST[$request];
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $result = stripslashes($result);
        }
        $link = Repo::db_connect();
        $result = mysql_real_escape_string($result, $link);
        Repo::db_close();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Исходя из мануала: "Подготавливаемые  запросы используются для повышения эффективности, когда один запрос выполняется многократно".

"Если параметризованный запрос запускается лишь раз, это приводит к большему количеству клиент-серверных обменов данными, нежели при выполнении простого запроса."

То есть если запрос используется только один раз, то, естественно, лучше обычный query.

Comment: >Если параметризованный запрос запускается лишь раз, это приводит к большему количеству клиент-серверных обменов данными, нежели при выполнении простого запроса

Как правило, подобные запросы перебирают с помощью цикла `while()`, если не ошибаюсь, то он таскает запрос каждую итерацию. Если что, поправьте.

Comment: А если это $result->fetch_object() в цикле? По идее же $result весь получается за 1 раз, или я неправ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, лучше использовать подготовленные запросы, но не всегда конечно же. Всё, как правило, зависит от ситуации, если в запрос не передаются какие-либо внешние данные, то в данном случае лучше использовать обычный `query`, нежели `prepare`.

По фильтрациям POST/GET:

```
$_GET = array_map('stripslashes', $_GET);
```

Чудеса бывают.

[**array_map()**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) or [**array_filter()**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: так если с моим приёмом данных(даже если с вашими доработками), вроде от всех иннъекций помогает..собираюсь поверх query и multi_query нагородить свой класс,или этот пример prepare(http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php 2 коммент сверху) тоже неплох/лучше?